# The importance of dimensions in the effective Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

I would like to examine the contributions from the new physics in any process in particle physics with the help of the Effective Lagrangian method.

In this method, the standard model Lagrangian plus a combination of possible new physics is available with additional Lagrangian. The dimensions of additional Lagrangians continue as 5, 6, 7, 8 etc.

Which of the contributions from the new physics is the most important and why is it important?

Comment: What do you mean by “*the* new physics”?

Comment: Here I mean beyond the Standard Model as new physic. For example, for the gamma gamma-> W W process, we take into account the effect of the WWGAMMA vertex from the dimension 6 effective lagrangian to deviate from the standard model cross-section. For this process, if we take into account the contributions from the dimensions 7, 8, 9.. f the WWGAMMA vertex, I wonder whether the contribution arising from the dimension 6

Answer (score 1):

You refer to the so called Standard Model Effective Field theory, where the Standard Model is extended with a tower of effective operators of canonical dimension $D > 4$ suppressed by the high scale of new physics $\Lambda \gg M_W$.   A complete basis for the dimension six operators was determined here

```
B.Grzadkowski, M.Iskrzynski, M.Misiak and J.Rosiek, JHEP 10 (2010) 085 [arXiv 1008.4884].
```

There is only one dimension 5 operator, the so-called Weinberg operator that gives neutrinos a Majorana mass term after electroweak symmetry breaking.

The Lagrangian is written as

$$ 
\mathcal{L}_{\rm{eff}} = \mathcal{L}_{\rm{SM}} + \frac{1}{\Lambda} C_{D=5} O^{D=5} + \frac{1}{\Lambda^2}C_{D=6} O^{D=6} + \cdots
$$
where $O^{D=n}$ represents operators of canonical dimension $n$. The coefficients $C_{D=n}$ are generically expected to be of order $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Note that there are infinite terms in your effective Langragian of increasingly high canonical dimension.  Each of those terms comes suppressed by appropriate powers of $1/\Lambda$.   The power counting of the effective theory is then given by this expansion in $1/\Lambda$.   Power counting refers to the organizing principle of an effective theory and it tells you which contributions are more important, so you can calculate physical observables to a given order to accuracy by keeping the most relevant terms from the effective Lagrangian and neglecting higher order contributions.

That said and given that there is only one dimension 5 operator in the effective theory (violating lepton number in two units), most of the processes receive the new physics dominant contribution from the dimension six terms.  At tree level, your amplitude will generally look like

$$\mathcal{A} \sim \mathcal{A}_{\rm{SM}} + \frac{1}{\Lambda^2} \mathcal{A_{D=6}} $$

Here we are neglecting subleading contributions to the amplitude from higher order terms which are suppressed by $\mathcal{\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\Lambda^4})}$.